How can I display an error when I enter an invalid parameter in the app command autocomplete in discord.py?
I want to display an error message like the one in this image:

I am using discord.py to create a Discord bot with command autocomplete functionality. I want to display an error message when a user enters an invalid parameter in the command autocomplete. However, I’m not sure how to handle and display errors for invalid parameters in this context. Can you provide guidance on how to implement this feature?

discord.py error-handling doc

it doesn't show in describe parameter. see the picture.

I'm afraid you cannot achive that. Infact, according to the documetation (check the warning)

The choices returned from this coroutine are suggestions. The user may ignore them and input their own value.

So, the input of the user can never be invalid on autocompletes commands.
And more in general, you can never customize that red error on slash commands (as far as I know).
